# verificar data ate 2 meses ao atual

Tags: php

Estou implementando um sistema financeiro e preciso limitar a geração de faturamento no máximo 2 meses.

porém sem sucesso...

```
<?php

    $mes_seguinte2 = str_replace('0', '', date('m', strtotime('+2 months', strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))));

    $ultimoMesMAIS2 = str_replace('0', '', date('m', strtotime('+2 months', strtotime(date('m', $dataEmpresa['mes_gerado_receitas'])))));

    if($mes_seguinte2 > $ultimoMesMAIS2){
        $resultado_subtracao = $mes_seguinte2 - $ultimoMesMAIS2;
    }elseif($mes_seguinte2 < $ultimoMesMAIS2){
        $resultado_subtracao = $ultimoMesMAIS2 - $mes_seguinte2;
    }

    if ($mes_seguinte2 == $ultimoMesMAIS2) {
        # NAO PROSSEGUE

        echo '<script>alert("Faturamento ja gerado para o mes seguinte.")</script>';
    }else{
        # PROSSEGUE NORMALMENTE ...
    }
?>
```

se alguém pensar em outra forma tbm serve...

Comment: Dá uma olhada se [algum destes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=comparar+data+%5Bphp%5D) funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Foi mais simples do que parecia, é só botar os nervos pra pensar...

```
$mes_atual = date('m');
$mes_atual_mais_um = date("m", strtotime("+1 month"));
$mes_gravado = $data_itl7->ultimo_faturamento;

$execucaoFattura = '0';
if($mes_atual == $mes_gravado){
    $execucaoFattura = '1';
}elseif($mes_atual > $mes_gravado){
    $execucaoFattura = '1';
}elseif($mes_atual < $mes_gravado){
    if ($mes_atual_mais_um == $mes_gravado) {
        $execucaoFattura = '20'; // mensagem de limite de fatura de 1 mes atingido
    }else{
        $execucaoFattura = '1';
    }
}
```

Dessa forma o script irá pegar qualquer mês anterior não faturado e faturar..

O detalhe é que ele irá permitir faturar para o próximo mês em relação ao atual.